# Uniquely identifying java processes with same name

Tags: grep, java, ps

I have two java processes which run using the same file name, `MyApp.jar` (for example).

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar
```

These jars exist in different places and use different configurations.

I want to be able to kill one process, but don't know how to distinguish between the two. I execute:

```
 ps aux | grep [M]yApp.jar
```

And get:

```
admin    21509  0.8  0.1 1199908 20484 ?       Sl   08:21   0:00 /usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar
admin    21585  6.7  0.1 1199764 20084 ?       Sl   08:21   0:00
```

I've thought of creating the process with some dummy parameter to be able to distinguish them:

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar MyAppTheFirst
```

and

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -jar MyApp.jar MyAppTheSecond
```

But this seems a bit wrong to me. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't get it, you have a PID right there, the second column

Comment: I don't know which is which though.

Comment: @PeterWood Which *is* which?  If you can't tell them apart, what makes one deserving of death more than the other?

Comment: @depquid They are configured differently and performing different tasks. Sometimes one may need restarting with a new configuration, or with a new version of the `jar`, or needs stopping as the service it is using is down and the logs are just filling up, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [why do you want to kill any of them?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) If a process is using too many resources you can just get the PID in `top`:

```
top -n 1
```

If they need to be restarted on a periodic basis or to react to outside stimuli, use [process management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement):

```
while true
do
    java -jar MyApp.jar &
    my_app_pid=$!
    while ! whatever_makes_me_think_my_app_should_be_restarted
    do
        sleep 60
    done
    kill $my_app_pid
done
```

Comment: I have many processes which have control scripts in `/etc/init.d/` which I can just say `stop`, `start`, `restart`. I recently deployed a new one which reused an existing `jar` and but it kills the wrong process. The process management link provided shows me that I'm probably doing it all wrong, but I have to fit into the system, or at least, it's easier if I do, even if it's not ideal. Hmm, people and processes... it is an XY problem.

Comment: My colleague helped me solve this. We now pass a unique system property to `java` using `-D`, and we can recover this with a `grep`. I like both the top answers as you've both helped me in different ways. Yours was more educational, the other more on task. I like questioning the cause of the problem too, and appreciate you pulling that on me.

Answer (score 2):

Changing parameters makes a difference to the application thus it's not the best idea. You could change $0 i.e. the program name itself. Most programs don't care about that but some change their behaviour based on that (e.g. if you can call the same binary by different names like IIRC with mtools and busybox):

```
bash -c 'exec -a mysleep sleep 100'
ps aux | grep sleep
hl       20818  0.0  0.0   5732   576 pts/10   S+   10:01   0:00 mysleep 100
```

or you use the environment:

```
bash -c 'IDSTRING=PROC1 exec sleep 100'
PID=20936
tr '\0' '\n' </proc/"$PID"/environ | grep IDSTRING
IDSTRING=PROC1
```

or you start the process with a wrapper script which writes the PID and additional information (for telling the processes apart) into a log file.

Comment: So [`exec -a` passes `mysleep` as the zeroth argument to `sleep`](http://ss64.com/bash/exec.html). That's useful. I'll have to work out how to make it work with `jar` files. Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

The only way which can help is to determine the bigger PID number.. the bigger one is the later ran process..**BUT NOT ALWAYS**

Comment: I'm running a server, and processes are started and stopped at various times by various people. I don't know which will be more recent.

Comment: How can you claim anything that is so obviously wrong?